# asp.net core mvc tag helper for bootstrap toggle

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am currently writing an asp.net core mvc app and I am new to .net core.  I am excited about tag helpers and I am trying to wrap my brain around them.  The simple ones I get and have made a couple, but the one that I really need is to replace the `<input type="checkbox">` with [bootstrap toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/).

I have been able to get the display of the toggle working using my custom "boolean" tag helper

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="IsBusiness"></label>
        <boolean asp-for="IsBusiness" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="IsBusiness" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
```

However the problem I am having is saving the value of the checkbox/toggle when the user turns it on and then clicks save.  I am getting an error: `"The value 'on' is not valid for Login Is A Business?."` in the form validation.

Can anyone please help me figure this out, is this going to need a hidden field or something?

Here is my tag helper so far:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

namespace Bidz4Hire.Utility.TagHelpers
{
    // Creates <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" />
    [HtmlTargetElement("boolean")]
    public class BooleanTagHelper : InputTagHelper
    {

        public BooleanTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator) : base(generator)
        {
        }

        public string AspFor { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
        output.TagName = "input";
        output.TagMode = TagMode.SelfClosing;

        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("id", For.Name);
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("name", For.Name);
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("data-toggle", "toggle");
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("data-on", "Yes");
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("data-off", "No");
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("value", "true");  //so the checked value returned is "true" not "on"
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(For.Model) == true) //check the model value
        {
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("checked", "checked"); //turns the toggle to "Yes" initially
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so after hours of messing around trying different things and scouring the Internet I finally figured it out.  I have edited the code above to the working version.

Basically you need to do two things:

1. output an attribute "value" set to "true" so when the checkbox is checked (toggle set to "Yes") the value returned is "true" instead of "on", which is the default for checkboxes.
2. Check the model property and add an attribute for "checked" if it is true.

I have highlighted both in the original post with comments.

I hope this helps someone else out there as I wasted a lot of time figuring this out.  Toggles look WAY better than checkboxes in modern web apps so it was well worth the effort IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate your solution, just wanted to point out that to use this you have to add your dll to the _ViewImports.cshtml file.

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, DLLOfCustomHelper
```

I don't have enough rep to comment on your answer.